Disabling a cart while moving
My first time writing, although I have perused here before.
I am writing a chase scene in which horsemen are chasing a cart and I need the rider to be able to destroy or disable a cart wheel in the chase. I immediately thought of a spear-in-the-spokes, but given that the wheel is on an axle as the only fixed point--that wouldn't work. Or would it? I guess the question is: what sort of attack would immobilize or destroy a wagon wheel?
Technology level is medieval. The cart is large, has wooden wheels, and is being pulled by a troika of three horses across a plain, if it matters.
Thanks!
Paul
Edit: clarified that it is a cart/wagon and not a chariot.

Presumably the axel is attached to a cart, which is itself a fixed point. Not sure I see the issue with that approach - unless you say it doesn't work - but why?

Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. Also worth looking at the [ask] section then perhaps editing your question with details (i.e. a description of the cart and available weapons/tools/tree-trunks etc.. How strong are their spears relative to the spokes?)

Chariots and carts are different. A spear shaft would probably stop a chariot, but a heavy cart wheel might just snap it. Even if possible, it seems a lot simpler and more plausible to target the horses. Does it have to be the wheel?

@user111403 You are forgetting that the average spear tip, socket, and braces are made out of metal and that the shaft is typically made out of exceptionally durable woods like oak or ash were as wheels were typically made of softwoods like pine to save on weight and cost.  The typical cart wheel will break before the typical spear.

why attack the cart, attack a horse one horse down takes all of it down and its a lot easier.

@Nosajimiki the socket may not be long enough to catch in the wheel on its own, if not it won't help here, but point taken regarding the wood. Even so it seems a lot easier and just as effective to target the horses.

FYI: A cart is a 2 wheeled vehicle, typically drawn by 1 draft animal, which is probably why so many answers don't sound applicable to what you are trying to ask.  What you are describing in your updates is either a wagon (if it has 4 wheels and used for heavy cargo) or a carriage (if it has 4 wheels and is used just for moving people).  You should probably update your language accordingly.  Also troika were not invented until the 17 century which is well after the medieval period.  So, your wagon should be using either a 2 or 4 horse harness at that tech level

Step one, fell the horse. Conan the Barbarian.

Provide a picture of your cart. If it's raised on suspension then no. If the wheels come half way up the side of the cart, then maybe.

The weak points of any chariot/cart

The driver
The animals
The harnesses (binding the animals to the yoke)
The shaft
The wheels


Focus on the wheels
It's important to understand that you might need to impose weaknesses as a fact of narrative necessity.

While "modern" cart wheels were banded/rimmed with steel, they were not originally so. This would make them susceptible to an ax or heavy sword. In fact, driving an ax into the wheel (let's say the wheel is solid and not spoked) would cause the cart to jump each time the ax head came around to the ground, which would drive it in deeper, causing greater weakness until the wheel failed.

I can't prove it right now, but I believe that spokes were also, eventually, armored with a metal "star" that formed around the hub and went up the spokes. While this wasn't proof against things like sticking something thick between the spokes, they strengthened the spokes significantly. However, choose to do without. Everything metal cost more. However, a casual stick (aka, spear shaft) probably wouldn't do it (well... it would work for suspension of disbelief) but a sword would. There's always the wrist-breaking moment when the object d'jour is torn from the protagonist's hand... which seems to be ignored a LOT in movies, which also seem to think it's trivial to throw such an object into the fast-moving spokes. There's gotta be a YouTube video somewhere showing how hard this really is, but let's focus.

There's nothing like the antagonist's chest of ill-gotten booty that can be dropped in front of one of the wheels. Don't sell this short! Chariots (and even carts) weren't all that fired capable or stable. No shock absorbers. No leaf springs. Just a sudden square, heavy thing that's either going to stop the chariot dead in its tracks or cause such a bump that the driver might just have problems regaining control of the chariot.

Then there's dropping something between the wheel and the chariot body. Something big enough to wedge itself in there and stop the wheel from turning. I have no idea how much space was between the average chariot body and its wheel, but it couldn't be so large that you'd need a huge tree trunk to do it. I'd say use a henchman. Extra on the set! Or maybe you have a chain with a grappling hook on both ends... try to drop the hooks down fore and aft of the axle.

And then there's one of my favorite scenes from A Funny Thing Happened On The Way To The Forum. If you're younger than 40 and choose to watch the show, hold your breath... It's 1960s take on women would definitely never appear in today's movies... but it's so honking funny! Anyway... pour something flammable on the wheel and set it ablaze! Might take a few minutes, but at the speed those wheels turn, they'll burn to instability in no time!


One last thing...
It's very believable that only some metal would be used on a chariot. Metal's heavy. One of the major reasons for using spokes is the reduction in weight, which allowed for either faster movement or the ability to haul more stuff (like an archer). Those metal rims probably arrived early on when spokes started to get used because, lacking a solid wheel, the wheel rim was suddenly very weak. However, whether or not steel rims make a difference to you really depends on the size of the ax, right? So, don't get carried away thinking there's ways to make chariots perfectly defensible. They weren't.

Thank you for the feedback. Some useful info here about metal being used to strengthen wheels. Just a note that the vehicle is a cart/wagon and not a chariot. I apologize for any confusion and have removed the reference to chariot in the original question.

+1 for Sanskrit written with cuneiform!

Just for completeness, also not pictured are sūtás, the driver and rathesthās, the warrior.

@PaulDirks To be honest, everything I said applies to a cart with one exception: a cart could operate with three wheels so long as the damaged wheel was on the rear axle. Technically it could operate for a while with a damaged front wheel, but the first time a rock or bump in the road hit the axle it could (probably would) bring down the horses.

I don't really see how one could solidly drive an axe into a wheel that's rotating at 30mph or more. Even if it stuck, the axe hitting the ground will in all likelihood make it fall out, not drive it in deeper.

@NuclearHoagie Driving the ax isn't the problem. You're correct that it's a roll of the dice a to whether it drives deeper or gets kicked out. However, this Stack is in the business of suspension of disbelief. We're not physics-lite.

Bike wheels are mounted on forks, which trap sticks against spokes as you describe. Wagon/chariot wheels are not. To trap your spear against the frame requires either passing it through both wheels simultaneously, or driving the point implausibly deep into the ground. Otherwise the haft will pivot, clatter loudly, and rattle its way out in any but the most unlikely of angles.

@JayMcEh I'd say you were right except for the big boxy thing in the middle used to carry people and goods. There are plenty of things to disrupt the rotation of the wheel without the convenience of forks. And like I mentioned to NuclearHoagie, the goal of this stack is suspension of disbelief. We're not physics-lite.

Carts VS Wagons
Since I answered this question, the OP has edited his question indicating that he probably means a wagon or carriage, not a cart.  A cart is a 2 wheeled vehicle, typically drawn by 1 draft animal, whereas wagons and carriage have 4 wheels and were typically pulled by 2 or more draft animals. This is an important distinction because disabling a single wheel on a cart, even for a moment, can cause a catastrophic failure for the vehicle whereas a wagon can still mostly function on 3 wheels.
To disable a cart: Aiming the spear between the spokes will be enough to stop it
In the city where I grew up, it was a common prank (or more accurately, a form of aggravated assault) to throw sticks into the bicycle wheels of someone riding by to lock the wheel up and send the rider flying over his handlebars.  The bike would usually be fine, but the stick would get stuck in the spokes of the wheel and pined against the bike's frame.  This would stop the wheel from being able to turn effectively putting the breaks on it.
In the case of a cart, as long as it is trying to move forward, the wheel will clamp the spear into place so that it can not fall out, and the wheel can not turn.  If the wheel on just one side of the cart is locked up like this, then it will not be able to roll straight anymore; so, there is a good chance that the cart will fishtail and flip if it is going fast enough, or simply become too difficult to steer if it does not.
The only way to unlock your wheel is to come to a complete stop and hope the spear falls out on its own, in which case who ever was chasing you will in that moment be able to catch you can pull you out of the cart.
What if there is enough space between the frame and wheel for the spear to pass vertically?
This could be even worse for the cart because the spear's tip would be driven down into the ground while it is still threaded between the spokes.  In this case, either the spear or the spokes ares more likely to snap because you have the full weight of the cart driving into the spear instead of just the momentum of the wheel.
That said, a typical wheel spoke will break more easily than a spear.  Spears were usually made from heat treated hardwoods like oak or ash, and depending on the exact spear, the part of the shaft that the spoke makes contact with may be reinforced by a steel socket or braces. In contrast, wagon wheels were typically made from softwoods like pine to save on cost and weight; so, even if the spokes of the wagon look tougher because of their size, they are probably going break more easily.
No matter what breaks though, it will significantly increasing the impulse of the asymmetrical stop making flipping or otherwise losing control of the wagon even more likely.
To disable a wagon: you'll have to attack the horses
Since a wagon wheel is more likely to break your spear, and less likely to actually stop the wagon even if you do jam a wheel up, this only leaves the horses.  Kill or even wound a horse, and the rider might quickly lose control of the wagon.  This would of course work for a cart too, but depending on how determined your attackers are, may not be the preferable option.
Attacking the horses is more dangerous for everyone involved.  Horses are relatively intelligent, strong, and slightly vindictive 1-ton animals making them unpredictable when threatened or hurt so there is a good chance that they will just steer the wagon right into their attacker trying to protect themselves. Or fear could drive them to run places a horse would normally refuse to go giving the cart driver a chance to escape through brambles, across a river, or over a cliff, even if his horses don't all survive the encounter.

There's a staggering amount of cartoon/action-movie physics in the other answers, too much to fit in comments.
Embedding an axe in a moving wagon wheel is perhaps technically possible but terribly unlikely, and rotation driving it deeper instead of dislodging it is lottery-level absurd. Metal was added to wheels to protect against collisions with other wheels (particularly in the cases of chariots) or against cumulative wear and tear, not to make them more resilient against single melee weapon attacks. Wood is already remarkably resilient against single melee weapon attacks. Some folks have never tried to chop down even a small tree, and it shows.
Briefly igniting a moving wheel, even with napalm-equivalent, would only superficially scorch the wood before the volatiles burned off. Wood only truly burns when it's heated enough to start releasing gases that fuel continued combustion, which is why a campfire takes more work (and time) than just spraying a log with butane and striking a match. Nitrocellulose burns fast but unless you contain and/or direct that pressure in (for example) a sealed metal tube, "burn fast" is all it does. This is why amateur magicians, many of them literal children, generally survive the process of using flash paper.
A stick in the wheels of a bike works because the spokes pin it against the fork, not the frame-- and wagon wheels do not have forks. People positing the relative strengths of various materials are all missing the point that even an infinitely strong rod put through the spokes of a cart wheel will just pivot around and bounce out unless it is very, very firmly secured at one and preferably both ends. No, throwing a spear into the dirt does not count as "very, very firmly secured" unless a certified demigod is throwing the spear. No, the turning of the wheel will not drive a spear deeper into the ground, it will be applying a circular motion at an angle that could hardly be more ideal to pry it free if the tip did somehow lodge particularly well. A sufficiently strong shaft that was passed through both wheels on a given axle would, I admit, work the same way as a stick in bike wheels. But that's a perfectly timed launch of a very heavy shaft moving at near bullet speeds to pass through both moving wheels and somehow arrest itself to not continue passing through either wheel, and if you've got that magical oversized sniper ballista available there are bigger and much easier targets like "the driver, the horses, or the cart itself".
Credit where it's due, too. JBH was correct that an anvil/stout chest/tree trunk unexpectedly in front of a wheel would have a good chance of breaking something or even overturning a cart, and at the very least would make any driver (who didn't know they were under attack) stop to see what was going on. A deep and narrow hole along the cart track ruts (and hidden by a some strategically scattered small branches) can accomplish the same thing with fewer worries about timing, although it obviously would pose issues for traffic before the intended target arrived.
JBH's grappling hook, attached to a quite stout rope tied to a nearby tree would definitely work if you can get it hooked to an axle or wheel. That's a challenging toss at speed but not silly, especially if you have multiple simultaneous attempts. The same can be accomplished with a long line tied to a tree at both ends-- wait until the wheel drives over the rear part of the loop, then raise the front line so the wheel passes under it, and let go. Requires no aim or special equipment, just a bit of timing that should be very manageable at the speed wagons move at when not actively being pursued. But with all sincerity, grappling hooks are much more fun.

Getting a rope stuck around the axle could destroy it, if it is long and sturdy enough. Even just making it unable to turn would do enough to slow the cart down.

I would recommend a mix between a Bola https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolas and a grappling hook https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grappling_hook cat of nine tails.. The bola catches one of the spokes of the wheel, and starts to wrap itself around - the hooks take hold in whatever they find, human, animal, wood, thin metall sheets- and rip and tear. Finally, those grappling hooks can also catch parts of the ground or whatever is around- brining the cart to a full stop.
Alternatively - coat a rope made of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrocellulose with a leathersheet - and watch it "explode/ignite" once it gets dragged into the spoke. Let there be Mayhem.

Nitrocellulose was not invented until the 1800s, the OP's setting is medieval.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid#History could have been discovered way earlier

Nitrocellulose used as described would do nothing but startle the horses. Like gunpowder it's a low explosive, thus it burns and produces expanding gases very quickly, but not so quickly that it bursts the barrel of a cannon or firearm. If you want a destructive explosion with nitrocellulose or with gunpowder you need an inflexible (mostly) sealed container, and/or a non-portable quantity.

Sealed container- like the bearing of a wheel, into which a rope wraps ever tighter, sealing it off, before it reaches temperature of ignition?

No, not like that. Why would it wrap into the bearing in the first place, much less "tighter and tighter"? I don't know what kind of RPM you think wagon axels are moving at or how adhesive your "leathersheet" is, but winding like a spindle is simply not in the cards. And if you some how did manage to wind it, it's still just a leather tube. It'll pop, not explode.

You could have upt to 30 mph, wheel radius 1 meter, thats 256 rpm, with a circumference of 10 cm, thats 2.5 minutes for a rope of 10 meters.. wow that is indeed not enough.. i retract that..

The grappler is a very simple device which is used by the police to do just the same thing. Although the mechanism which controls it is now automated, the device itself is simple: A set of two arms with straps between them. The grappler in ancient time could have been inserted by manually unfolding it and pushing it under the wheel.
Changes are needed to make it fit for the old-era technology. For instance, the current grappler relies on the rough surface of the tire to "grap" by using friction. A possible work around is either coating the straps with a high friction material or inserting hooks on given areas, thus allowing the hooks to grap the spokes instead. As the video shows, the grappler is connected to the car, which provided all the counteractive force to stop the escaping vehicle. One way I can think of is letting the attacker's horse pass by the cart, therefore getting the grappler close enough to the wheel.
